# Error in decalring class and object for JS

Tags: javascript

My class declaration is:

```
class Category {
  constructor(id, name, type, url) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.url = url;
    this.assets = [];
  }

  set assets(value) {
    this.assets = value;
  }
}
```

I have imported it into my main class using `import Category from './beans';` and I am trying to declare an object of this class using

```
let category = new Category("1", "2", "3", "4");
```

I am getting the error:

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _beans.Category("1", "2", "3", "4")')
```

How to solve this?

---

**EDIT** It seems that the `assets` declaration in the constructor of `Category` was causing the error. When I removed it, it worked. Now the question is how do I  keep a variable in my `Category` class which will be initialised later and not in the constructor?

Comment: Missing `export` here: `class Category {`

Comment: @Rajesh That doesn't work. Now my app just crashes without sending any error.

Comment: Have you tried logging `Category` to the console in the file you're importing it in to check if it's defined?

Comment: @Aplet123 I tried logging just now and it came `undefined`. How do I make it defined?

Comment: @khateeb Can you show me how you exported module?

Comment: @khateeb following is the import/export syntax: `export class Category; import { Category } from file-name;` and `export default class Category; Import Category from file-name;`

Comment: @Rajesh 
    export default class Category {
      constructor(id, name, type, url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.url = url;
        this.assets = [];
      }

      set assets(value) {
        this.assets = value;
      }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your new question about how to save instance variables. Unlike some other languages you can't declare instance variables outside of the constructor (or another instance method). So you would put these in your constructor but you don't have to know the value ahead of time. For instance:

```
class Category {
    constructor(id, name, type, url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.url = url;
        this.assets = [];
        this.myVar = null;
    }
    setMyVar(myVar) {
        this.myVar = myVar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was using the `set assets(value)` instead of a normal function. Any idea why this crashes?

Comment: Getters and setters are special. The problem was that by declaring assets as a setter you were actually calling it as part of your constructor by doing this.assets = [], which was in turn calling the setter again and again in an infinite loop. If you want to use getters/setters you'll have to prefix the instance variable name with something when you set it internally. For example if this.assets is the setter, use this._assets in the setter itself.